# Styling an Input Field

Tags: html, css

How can I give the input field below the characteristics listed below?

Characteristics:

-Text typed into the field starts in the upper left corner and starts on another line (wraps?) when the right border of the field is reached.

-A scroll bar appears if the text is more than what can fit into the field.

-The text is in Courier font.

Thanks in advance,

John

```
echo '<form  action="http://www...com/sandbox/comments/comments2.php" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" value="'.$_SESSION['loginid'].'" name="uid">
    <input type="hidden" value="'.$submissionid.'" name="submissionid">  
    <input type="hidden" value="'.$submission.'" name="submission">


    <label class="addacomment" for="title">Add a comment:</label>

    <input class="commentsubfield" name="comment" type="comment" id="comment" maxlength="1000">  

    <div class="commentsubbutton"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></div> 
</form>
';
```

Some relevant CSS:

```
.commentsubfield {margin-left: 30px; margin-top: 30px; width: 390px; height: 90px; border: 1px solid #999999; padding: 5px; }
```

Comment: I tried textarea... and the submit button disappeared... is it possible to have a textarea and a submit button simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly possible, your textarea may be overlapping your submit button. It is hard to tell with the code you have currently presented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might sound pretty elementary, but why not just use a textarea? It does exactly what you are describing

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

[textarea](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)

edit: to better show what the textarea should look like

```
<textarea class="commentsubfield" name="comment" id="comment" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
```

of note, textarea does not have a maxlength attribute, to limit length in the textarea you would need to use some javascript.

Comment: I'm not familiar with textarea... would I just replace the word "input" with "textarea"?

Comment: Yes, that is what you would do John. :-)

Comment: OK, I tried it, and the submit button disappeared... any ideas as to why?

Comment: OK, I figured it out.  @klabranche... I need to do more than just replace "input" with "textarea"... I also needed to add a </textarea>:

<textarea class="commentsubfield" name="comment" type="comment" id="comment" maxlength="1000"></textarea> 

When I did that, the submit button remained.

Comment: You should also add the cols and rows attributes. Yes the browser will work without them but to create valid html those attributes are required.

Comment: @John..... Sorry about that.  Yes, textarea is a different tag.  I was looking at the sample given in the answer more than what your question was in the comment....

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you should use a [textarea](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) instead of a `<input type="text"`.

The CSS would be

> .commentsubfield {
>       font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
>       overflow: auto; }